# Excel conditional IF value greater than zero only reporting TRUE

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a column containing values such as: -10, 0, 32, 70, -23

I want to create a column based off the first column, and this column should display either TRUE or FALSE values. It should display TRUE if the value of the first column is greater than 0, and FALSE if the value is equal 0 or less than 0 (so those minus values).

I used the simple formula:

```
=IF(O9 > 0,"TRUE","FALSE")
```

But the output of the column is TRUE for everything, even for instances where the value was 0 or less than zero. I even tried > 1 but it's the same. I don't understand what I am doing wrong!

Thank you!

Comment: You're probably dealing with *text*, not numbers. Try `=--O9>0`.

Comment: Are these real numbers or text? You can check it with `ISNUMBER` function.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're dealing with *text-that-looks-like-numbers*.

Use the double unary `--` to force conversion to a number, and you can also drop the `IF` completely - the result of the `>` comparison is `TRUE` or `FALSE` already:

```
=--O9>0
```